# How to change page title when generated from blueprint?

Tags: java, confluence

I'm trying to setup a Blueprint plugin for Confluence on our company's server. We're setting up a knowledge base and need some specific fields to be added as well as the title to be prefixed. I've read the different tutorials to create blueprints and tested them out and finally ended by finding out that the documentation is outdated.

So now I'm stuck on where I should modify the data sent to create a new page from a blueprint using the data in the wizard dialog? Am I supposed to do this with a ConectProvider or is it better to do so with an event listener? In both cases what class should I extend or what interface should I implement? All the example or answers I've found use either a BlueprintEvent or a BlueprintContextProvider which are either depreciated either non existent in the Atlassian Java doc (https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/).

Any link to recent tutorials, documentation or any kind of information will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using the latest version on Confluence.

Answer (score 1):

The information on [Write an intermediate blueprint plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-blueprints/write-an-intermediate-blueprint-plugin) provides some details on how to do what you want to do. Your question may imply that you already tried it. In this case maybe you could add some hints on why you think it is out-of-date (note that the no-args constructor is deprecated, but there is a substitute)?

To access the BlueprintContext extend the AbstractBlueprintContextProvider which is part of

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>confluence-create-content-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${create.content.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The artifacts are available from Atlassian's Artifact Repository at https://maven.atlassian.com/.

Then you have access to the information collected in the wizard. I think this is the standard way to do it.

Here is the documentation of that class (copied from the source code - I have found no link to an online API documentation):

```
 * Provides a {@link BlueprintContext} for Blueprint Template renders.
 *
 * "context-provider" implementations in "content-template" plugin modules should extend this class rather than
 * implementing {@link ContextProvider} directly.
```

For more information on how to access the source code: [Do we get access to the Confluence source code?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=179439018)